# Azure Table Storage data source for Grafana?

Tags: azure, nosql, cloud, grafana

Is there any (relatively easy) ways to visualize data from Azure Table Storage in Grafana?

I tried looking for existing datasource connectors, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Power BI has one. But nothing on Grafana. Please add as answer if you find any workarounds like piping from Table Store to an intermediatory low priced store which is supported by Grafana.